# Is there a better term than "NIH" (Not Invented Here) for my mentality?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I've many times been called a "NIHer" by other programmers/"system designers". This basically means that they think that I "have to do it myself" and can't stand using something made by somebody else, which is perhaps *technically* true, but the thing is, that is not the "point" of my way of thinking.

It's not that I *want* to do all that work. In fact, I find it to be absolute *torture* and would much rather just use something that "somebody smarter than I" has perfected -- it's simply that I *must* do it, because I find that other people have always either over-thought or under-developed their "solutions", and every single time I have attempted to use free-of-charge "code software" of any kind, which is supposed to closely integrate with my own system (that is, **not** some kind of neat library that solves a very specific problem, on its own, and returns the answer), I find that it looks like absolute useless garbage to my eyes.

I simply need for things to be done in a certain way, and nobody else seems to agree on that, so I'm forced to make it myself.

But one other important reason is that, if I have intimate knowledge of the system, since I designed and coded it, I feel like it's got a much better chance of being secure, because other people always feel the need to cater to all kinds of "broad needs" whereas I know from experience what specific functions and "mechanisms" I need myself. If I had to make my stuff generic enough to appeal to a mass market, it would doubtlessly also get insanely convoluted and far from everything that seems "sensible" to me.

Furthermore, I find that attempting to "grasp" the code of anyone else's code project is essentially impossible unless it's a very minor library, so the idea of "vetting" their code and even "modify it to my needs" is so far detached from my reality that it's almost laughable.

I've actually many times attempted to "pick a part" from an existing software, such as the "differ" from Wikipedia's MediaWiki software, but it was hopelessly integrated into their very specific ways of doing things, and I could have spent an eternity trying to "rip it out" from MediaWiki and then try to adjust it to work in my system... so it was faster to "just do it myself".

I find this to be true again and again. There may be a lot of software out there, but how much is usable in practice? I find that I cannot rely on third parties, and thus I don't unless absolutely necessary. For example, to do something really complicated which is just way above my head, such as parsing the grotesque blobs people send as e-mail.

I don't feel like I have a "Not Invented Here syndrome". I would happily snap my fingers right now and automatically download to my desktop a .php file which is laid out according to my exact preferences and self-coded framework's structure, and does exactly what I want to accomplish, but this is just the same as saying that I wish I could snap my fingers to have the girl of my dreams appear right next to me and say: "Oh, you are so handsome and smart and your code is just beautiful!" ... It's meaningless because it's a pure fantasy and logically impossible. I know what happens if I go searching with DuckDuckGo for such a library: I'll find the same unmaintained, abandoned projects which vaguely do something related to the task, but doesn't do what I want and cannot be relied on.

What would better describe me?

Comment: How about "Not Acceptable Here".  It also conveniently spells, "Nah!"

Comment: In your case, how about "unreliable" or "inefficient"?

Comment: 'Independent' is at least ballpark. 'Perfectionist' is perhaps too harsh if _everything_ you've tried from other workers has let you down. You want a car that works; it doesn't matter if the colour is not quite the most appealing shade of red. Self-reliant means not seeing any need for external aid rather than refusing it because it has always let you down. _As an aside, have others found that your products don't fit in with_ their _requirements?_

Comment: **Perfectionist**, **micromanager**, and **haughty** all see seem to fit the general pattern of things described here, but it's not clear what the specific aspect is that's being focused on.

Comment: This is the first roast request I've seen on ELU.